# How to round Unix Time-stamp to nearest half hour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Using JavaScript/jQuery.

I am trying to get the current timestamp for the nearest half hour.

For example, if it is currently 4:36pm 9/15/2017 I would like to get a timestamp for 4:30pm 9/15/2017.

Or if it was 11:53 pm 9/15/2017 I would need the timestamp for 12:00 **am** 9/**16**/2017.

Date.now() does not have any parameters for this so I'm a little stuck on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Make a date. Get the minutes with `.getMinutes()`. Round to either 0 or 30. Set the minutes to that with `.setMinutes()`. Call `.getTime()`.

Comment: Please at least make an attempt so there's some code we can help you fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the time in milliseconds, round that to the nearest `30*60*1000`, then convert that back to a date.

```js
var nowMil = new Date().getTime();
var roundedMil = Math.round(nowMil/1000/60/30) * 30 * 60 * 1000;
var roundedTime = new Date(roundedMil);
console.log(roundedTime);
```

Comment: This worked with a little change. Thanks. Keep in mind though I did ask for the timestamp, not date.

Comment: `roundedMil` contains the timestamp.